# what is happening with my climate data and treeclim package?

Tags: r

I'm attending to use the package treeclim to analyze my tree ring growth data and climate. I measured the ring-width and read into R using dplR function. However, when I correlated this width with the climate data, I keep an error message reading:

```
warning: solve(): system is singular; attempting approx solution
Error: solve(): solution not found
```

I have the chronology that looks like:

```
head(grow.crn.Picacho)
 std samp.depth
1844 0.7003587          1
1845 1.2323879          1
1846 0.9198607          1
1847 1.1984353          1
1848 1.2345595          1
1849 0.7616830          1
```

And my monthly climate:

```
head(prp_pic)
Year  p1  p2  p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12
1 1950  64  17  69 21 41  0  0  2 18  50  15  86
2 1951 110 134 133 29 18  2  0  0 28  29 184  58
3 1952  77  27 116 30 78  0  0  5  4  56  55  60
4 1953  67  71  59 66  0  0  0  0  1  48  59 107
5 1954  33  41 150 22  0  0  0  0  0   1  66  36
6 1955 196 198 134  7 20  1  0  0  0  88 115  87

head(temp_pic)
Year  tm1  tm2  tm3  tm4  tm5  tm6  tm7  tm8  tm9 tm10 tm11 tm12
1 1950  9.7 10.4 12.3 13.8 15.9 20.3 23.7 23.3 20.8 17.1 14.3  8.6
2 1951  8.5  8.6 11.4 13.2 13.9 19.8 21.7 22.0 20.1 15.0 12.1 10.8
3 1952  7.5  9.0 12.7 12.9 15.3 20.0 22.2 21.5 18.5 16.9 13.0  9.3
4 1953  8.1  8.7 10.7 13.3 17.7 18.9 22.8 23.7 20.8 16.2 13.9 11.4
5 1954  7.6  8.5 10.5 12.1 16.3 19.0 21.7 21.3 20.4 18.1 14.4 10.5
6 1955 11.4 10.2 11.0 14.8 18.1 20.6 22.6 23.2 21.9 17.1 14.0 12.0
```

And when I ran the code:

```
resp_clima <- dcc(chrono = grow.crn.Picacho, climate = list(prp_pic, temp_pic)  , selection = -10:10, method = "correlation", dynamic = "static", win_size = 35,win_offset = 1, start_last = TRUE, timespan = NULL, var_names = NULL, ci=0.05, boot = "std", sb=FALSE )
```

It give me the error. Where am I wrong?